# Entity Framework - Different behavior on different environments

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, wcf, entity-framework

I've recently started working with Entity Framework (version 4.1) and WCF.
I'm trying to make an n-tier asp.net application (.Net Framework 4.0), in which the data-layer consists of wcf services that internally use the entity-framework. The approach taken with the entity framework is model-first.

On my development environment i have both the asp.net application and the wcf services running on the IIS 7.5 under the same web site and under the same application pool (It's not great but it works). On the first access of any of the wcf services, the performance is quite poor, but on subsequent accesses it's OK. The reasons for the bad performance on the first access, are explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - e.g. the overhead associated with the view generation, preparation of the queries, etc,

After completing the development, I've set up a testing environment with 2 virtual machines - one server (IIS 7.5) that hosts the application front-end and another one (again IIS 7.5) that hosts wcf services - running in different machines, under different websites and different application pools.

I was expecting the same behavior, namely a slow first access to the services and subsequent accesses executing a lot faster, but all accesses to the services run slow.

The problem is not with the queries being heavy and it's not a problem with the network . I have executed an entity framework profiling tool, and apparently the overhead of generating the views and the preparation of queries exists on every call to the wcf service. The execution of the queries runs fast.

Essentially I'm trying to figure out why I am noticing different behaviors on different environments.

From what I've read, every time an AppDomain is created, the entity-framework executes the operations that are associated with the initial overhead. But does this mean for every call to a WCF service a new AppDomain is created?

Comment: Any chance the builds were debug in dev box, and release in testing environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Apparently the setup of the development machine had the June 2011 CTP of the .Net Framework installed, and the test environment machines had the standard .Net Framework 4.0. I have upgraded to .Net Framework 4.5 on all of the machines, and everything now works as expected.

Apparently the Entity Framework on .Net 4.0, on every request introduces the overhead of generating the views and compiling the queries. On the 4.2 version of the Framework and above, the behavior is more like what is described on the literature: the overhead only occurs on the first access.

The WCF AppDomain is created by the IIS Application Pool and is reused on several requests.

I appreciate your input Narayana