# MySQL Connector - Entity Framework

Tags: mysql, .net, frameworks, entity, connector

I have an application which is .NET connecting to a MYSQL back end. On both the development machine and the server I have MySQL Connector 6.5.5 installed, I use entity framework.

When I query the database on my local machine, and look at the generated SQL - the query consists of Select X, Y, Z inner join A inner join B Where C in (1,2,3).

However, when I deploy the exact same system to the live server, the query is completely changed to Select X, Y, Z, LEFT OUTER JOIN 1, LEFT OUTER JOIN 2, LEFT OUTER JOIN 3 Where 1 = C or 2 = C or 3 = C.

Firstly - I can't understand why the SQL doesn't match given that both machines have the same connector installed.

Secondly, the second version takes 10 minutes while the first version takes 10 seconds. How can I align the server to my development machine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Personally per personal experience i suggest you to check if there are other connections on the server.
In local environment you are sure that you are the only one connected to the database in live environment you are exposed to mysql port scan and also there's other query from other user and so on.
Second one are you sure that you have the same mysql database version on both machine ?It could be (I'm not sure) that for different mysql version there's different translation of mysql statement.

Also you can try to create a procedure to checking remote connection and local connection in order to understand if it require more time to connect to the database and so on.

Make some checks before being crazy.

Comment: Hi, the database is hosted on the web server, both environments connect to the same live database currently. It's 'local' when deployed, so it's the local one which is taking the longer time.

Comment: it's really strange......so it took more time when it is in local environment instead where it is deployed online it is more faster (sorry for the question but i'm italian and i want to be sure of what you means)

Comment: Yes. Both development machine and server connect to the live server database, so the development environment which is remote from the database is much quicker. The reason for this is the query formation I mentioned in my question. I just have to work out why the MySQL Connector is producing different SQL when deployed to the server!

Comment: take a look here seems same exactly issue; different configuration between remote server and local machine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350599/entity-framework-different-behavior-on-different-enviroments i hope it help